# Atom html snippets not working

Tags: code-snippets, atom-editor

I have been pulling my hair out trying to finds a solution to this problem.
I start typing `<a` then press ctrl-enter to open up the available snippets.

I would then be provided with just a list of tags (with the red V icon at the left), I was expecting to see a list of snippets (green right pointing arrow)  that could be selected and would auto complete the tag and closing tag.

The same functionality as seen on this blog post (HTML Paragraph) http://blog.atom.io/2015/05/15/new-autocomplete.html

It is my understanding that autocomplete-plus has snippets from autocomplete-HTML, auto-complete-CSS, autocomplete-atom-API, and autocomplete-snippets. And that these are all now bundled by default into the atom.

I have read many blogs and GitHub issues trying to find a solution and none have worked. my snippets.cson is empty (Ignoring comments)and it is my understanding that they are for custom snippets. I do not want custom snippets at the moment, I just want the defaults which are advertised on the autocomplete plus docs

Has anybody else had this issue or would know solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Atom snipped has a specific prefix, in case of the `<a>` tag it is just `a` (without the `<` character), so typing `a`<kbd>tab</kbd> pastes the snippet body tag.